# Finding and using the gradient of the loss wrt input with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am quite new to Tensorflow, although I used Keras in the past and I was comfortable with it. I am trying to replicate the results of a paper (the one about ODIN) that was written in Pytorch and I want to do the same but with Tensorflow. Basically, I need to:

1. Obtain the gradients of the loss with respect to the inputs.
2. Evaluate the gradient on an image.
3. Add the gradient and the image together (hence, perturbating the original image).
4. Feed this new "image" to the Network.

So I have a toy NN trained with MNIST:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)
```

And I read here that I could find the gradient with respect to the input by running the following.

```
grads = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)
grads[0]
```

But now I would like to perform the rest of the steps: evaluate the gradient on an image, add the gradient to perturbate the image and then call the predict function. So I would kinda like something like

```
tt = tf.add(model.input, grads[0])
model.predict(tt)
```

Obviously this does not work, but I just can't wrap my head around Tensorflow and its syntax and the way it works. I know it has to be something silly and easy to do, but I cannot understand how I should proceed. How can I effectively evaluate and sum the gradient with my image?